# ELCImagePicker - NuGet Package

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to pick multiple images from mobile gallery. For iOS, there is no Xamarin provision to achieve this goal. Suggestion is to use ELCImagePicker, but its not available in NuGet package list. As Xamarin.Forms doesn't allow Components to import, I find no help online to import [ELCImagePicker](https://components.xamarin.com/view/elcimagepicker) or any other choice for multiple image picker in iOS. Is there no way using Xamarin we can achieve the scenario above currently?

Comment: Really got stuck with Xamarin now. No support anywhere regarding multiple image picker. Hope might have chosen Phonegap instead. Now stuck with all the feature set completed but Multi-Image picker alone left. Requirement is like https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/ImagePicker-OLX

Comment: ELCImagePicker is no no longer supported. there is no any other option to do multiple image selection in xamarin forms. Except if someone create a new DLL like ELCImagePicker from native application. UIImagePickerViewController does not allow to select multiple images at same time. so this is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

ELCImagePicker is no longer supported. Try to use [GMImagePickerController](https://github.com/roycornelissen/GMImagePicker.Xamarin), I have used the same to pick multiple images from gallery in iOS. It is also supported in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try another libraries:

The following links are the function implementations of multiple selection from gallery on Android or iOS.

[GMImagePicker.Xamarin - IOS](https://github.com/roycornelissen/GMImagePicker.Xamarin)

[Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker - Android and IOS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker/)

Original answer:
[Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137294/multiple-image-selection-from-gallery)

Keep me informed if you were able to implement correctly.

I'm hope help you!